# Automatically Access Denied, What's Happening?

Tags: php, access-denied

Ok so I just resolved my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594748/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-in-c-xampp-htdocs-smasher-auth-php-on) and I need help AGAIN...
So I fixed the authentication code but now every time I log in to my profile, it says I'm not logged into my site. Here's the access-denied.php code:

```
<title>Access Denied</title>
<link href="loginmodule.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Access Denied </h1>
<p align="center">&nbsp;</p>
<h4 align="center" class="err">Access Denied!<br />
  You do not have access to this resource.</h4>
```

And Here's my auth.php code:

```
//Start session
session_start();

//Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
if(!isset($_SESSION['email']) || ($_SESSION['password'])){
    header("location: access-denied.php");
    exit();
}
```

And here's my profile page code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php include("inc/incfiles/loggedheader.php")?>
<?php
    require_once('auth.php');
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Member Index</title>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome <? if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_fname'])){
    echo $_SESSION['SESS_fname'];
} ?></h1>
<a href="member-profile.php">My Profile</a> | <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
<p>Welcome to your profile! </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Why can't I log into my profile? I know nothing about this type of PHP I'm barely still learning, my friend (who is helping me build my site) got the codes and just emails them to me.

Comment: I think there might be a problem with `|| ($_SESSION['password'])`

Comment: it used to be: (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '')) {
but that still doesn't work. I'm trying to get it to see the password from the database..

Comment: Dumb question: why do you need to store the password in the session?

Comment: What kind of database are you using? And what @Mike said; why store the password in the session?

Comment: like I said, I'm new to all of this. I don't really know what you mean by store the password in the session. Am I supposed to replace "session" or what?

Answer (score 0):

There are problem in line

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['email']) || ($_SESSION['password'])){
```

you do need to check second part (password check) of if condition. Here you are checking that if email not exists in session or password is exists in session. So even if email set and then page goto access denied due to second condition is true.  If necessary, you should use

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['email']) || !($_SESSION['password'])){
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['email']) || !isset($_SESSION['password'])){
    ...
}
```